# How to setup Jenkins with JUnit

Tags: jenkins, ant, junit, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

We have a `JUnit` test suite that we usually run from Eclipse. We have recently started a process of trying to get a better development environment. As part of this we have started building our project in `Jenkins`. We would also like it if it was possible to run the`JUnit` test suite during our build. To do this I think we need a way to execute the test suite from command line so that we can integrate them in `Jenkins` and parse their output.

How can we set up `Jenkins` to run our tests?

Comment: Do you use Maven or Ant or ...?

Comment: I have no clue of Maven or Ant we usualy run the suite from eclipse directly. And when we release the project we do that as a WAR file

Comment: Then learn Ant or Maven to build outside the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `junit` ant task during your build and let Jenkins run that task

Here are some lines we used on a project. Here launching a suite called `AllNonGWTTestCaseTests`

```
<target name="runTests" description="Run JUnit tests">
    <junit printsummary="yes" dir="test-classes" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="inst-classes" />
        </classpath>
        <test name="xxx.AllNonGWTTestCaseTests" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
            <formatter type="xml" />
        </test>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Building this will create the file result.xml. That configures an ant task.
Jenkins can launch this ant task. Take a look at your project configuration. Section `Build > Ant task`. Then in `Post-build Actions` just set the path to the xml file : result.xml

This should make Jenkins run the test suite as a post build action.

Comment: How do I go about setting up an ant executable.

Comment: Jenkins can launch ant task. Look at your project configuration. Section Build>Ant task. Then in Post-build Actions just set the path to the xml file : result.xml

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution (step by step) is here !

1)Add xUnit  Plugin to Jenkins

2)Add these below sample code **Execute Windows Batch Command** **under build section** (Command) of Jenkins.

```
javac xyxTest.java //compile your test class 
java xyzTest // run your test class
```

3) Add  "**Publish Junit test result report**"

Here is the link ,where you will find details of it.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_unit_testing.htm

Hope it will help!