# How can I configure my jenkins job in order to get test reports?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a repository on bitbucket (containing a java class and a test for that class), and Jenkins installed on my laptop.
I managed to create a jenkins job linked to the repository, but I am lost from where I have to add a post-build step in order to get the reports.

Comment: What reports you want ? What build system you use in your project ? Generally you use dedicated plugin for your build system e,g for maven it can be cobertura, jacoco, pmd etc. Next you install and setup proper plugins for Jenkis. In job item you call proper build targets, that will generate reports. Finally using, jenkins plugins, publish created reports.

Comment: I don't think i have any build system in place. I am really new to this and need more advice. How can I carry on from where I am now?

Comment: Ok, so how you compile your java code ? Do you use ant/maven/gradle etc ? What reports do you need ?

Answer (score 1):

What test framework are you using ?

E.g for `JUnit`.
To generate reports install [JUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) for Jenkins. Here you have example [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1j_GcoJxB0) that shows how to setup jenkins with junit. Additional reading about JUnint and Jenkins setup: [How to setup Jenkins with Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407560/how-to-setup-jenkins-with-junit).