# Junit test failed in jenkins build

Tags: java, jenkins, appium, appium-android

I need help.

So I want to make my automation running in jenkins job. I am using appium studio for information. For now my test can run on appium studio and eclipse. But when running build on jenkins I get error below:

[image]

My setup:

[image]

Build.xml:

[image]

Test result:

[image: test result]

Code:

```
package junit;
//package <set your test package>;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.junit.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class junit {
private String reportDirectory = "reports";
private String reportFormat = "xml";
private String testName = "tiket1adult";
protected AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = null;

DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

@Before
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
    dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
    dc.setCapability("testName", testName);
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "f5a19fd4");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.pegipegi.android");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".main.activities.SplashActivity");
    dc.setCapability("instrumentApp", true);
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
    driver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
}
 @Test
public void testtiket1adult() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='it_next' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[./*[@text='Tiket Pesawat']]]")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='CARI TIKET' and @width>0]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='CARI TIKET' and @width>0]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='per orang' and ./parent::*[./parent::*[(./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)]]]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Pesan']")).click();
}
 @After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the code as text and not as a picture. :)

Comment: Congrats on your first StackOverflow post! In addition to the suggestion by @npkllrif please also provide some logging output showing what/why/how the tests fail :)

Comment: already update @MaximilianC.

Comment: junit library is missing on classpath while executing the jenkins job... maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407560/how-to-setup-jenkins-with-junit

Comment: got error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\junit\build.xml:31: The <classpath> or <modulepath> for <junit> must include junit.jar if not in Ant's own classpath @TommyBrettschneider

Comment: for reference i need like this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvbIWlOFEEQ    
i already follow like video. but still can't success build in jenkins

Comment: @bandit1 try to use Maven build & mention the dependencies in pom.xml, since you are using build.xml you may need to upload the junit.jar with your project classpath or create folder under your project "lib" put your dependencies jar in that folder

Comment: @Manidroid yup i already copy all lib appium to my workspace in jenkins. test already run but with error bellow:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)

Comment: Then your libs are not set in your classpath thats y its showing error, try with maven dependency it will download and set your classpath